# How to represent corresponding date and time (with 9 digits right of decimal) from Vax 64 bit epoch

Tags: java, oracle

The issue at hand is the following:  1) Receive a Vax VMS 64 bit epoch time from hardware for which a TCP/IP socket connection has been established, 2) store the Unix equivalent epoch time into an oracle database table, 3) allow a user to query and display such time on a GUI so that the date format is MM/DD/YYYY and the time format is such that there are 9 digits to the right of the decimal (like 17:30:30.123456789).

I have successfully written the code to establish the TCP/IP socket connection to the hardware and process the received data.

In searching the internet I found an article that explains how to convert a Vax VMS 64 bit epoch time to a Unix epoch time.  The C function from this article is as follows:

```
void timevmstounix( long long *vmstimein, time_t *epochout )
{
    long long timevalue = *vmstimein;

    timevalue -= 0x07c95674beb4000ull;
    timevalue /= 10000000;
    *epochout = (time_t) timevalue;

    return;
}
```

From additional internet research it is my understanding that the Java data type equivalent (since Java 8) for long long and time_t C data types is a long.  Is this correct?

I have defined and built an oracle database table which contains a column of the type timestamp(9) to be able to retrieve a time with 9 digits to the right of the decimal.

The biggest issue/confusion I am having is on how I can take the resulting Unix epoch time and store it in this Oracle database column so that later when a user performs a query against the associated database table I can query this columns content with to_char(column_name, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.sssssssss') and it can be displayed with the correct required format.  Thanks for any assistance/suggestions/corrections you can provide.

Comment: Does http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16461/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-datetime-in-a-view help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work:

```
insert into <your_table> values( timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT' +
   numtodsinterval(<your unix value>/1000, 'SECOND') )
```

Comment: I am sure your suggestion will work, however the first hurdle I am struggling to overcome is how to generate the Java equivalent to the following line of code - timevalue -= 0x07c95674beb4000ull;
  provided in the c function timevmstounix presented in my initial/original post.  Everything I have tried gives me a syntax error.

Comment: Well, that's a different question then, no?